# Perl DBI MySQL Updates

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am wondering how you can print the results from the following Perl code snippet:

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
    $sth->execute();
```

I'd like to see what you would see if you typed "SELECT * FROM table_name; into mySQL and had the entire relation show up. Is there a return value from $sth that can be looped over and printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# BIND TABLE COLUMNS TO VARIABLES
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$id, \$product, \$quantity);

# LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
while($sth->fetch()) {
   print "$id, $product, $quantity <br />";
}
```

Comment: You don't need the leading `undef` for [`bind_columns`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#bind_columns) anymore.